# Find the solution of the differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Find the solution of the differential equation
$$\frac{dw}{dq}=-qw^2\sin(q^2)$$
satisfying the initial condition $w(0)=7$.

Following the pattern of previous similar problems, I assume the first step is separation of the variables on opposite sides, and then integration. I just don't quite know how to go about it. Multiplying by $dq$ makes the right side a jumble. Dividing by $w^2$ does similar things on the left.

Comment: A jumble? Separation of variables seem to be the way to go. What is the trouble more specifically?

Comment: So that yields dw = [-qw^2sin(q^2)]dq. How then do I get w^2 to the left side?

Comment: You multiply both sides by $1/w^2$ (or if you want, divide both sided by $w^2$).

Comment: Do both, that is multiply by $dq$ and divide by $w^2$. That should sort things out nicely, for integration. The integrations are trivial. The $dq$ needs a substitution for $q^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice $$\frac{d\omega}{dq}=-q\omega^2\sin(q^2)$$
$$\frac{d\omega}{\omega^2}=-q\sin(q^2)dq$$
$$\int \frac{d\omega}{\omega^2}=-\int q\sin(q^2)dq$$
$$\int \omega^{-2}d\omega=-\frac{1}{2}\int 2q\sin(q^2)dq$$
Let $q^2=t\implies 2qdq=dt$
$$\frac{-1}{\omega}=-\frac{1}{2}\int \sin(t)dt$$
$$\frac{-1}{\omega}=-\frac{1}{2}(-\cos (t))dt+c$$

$$\frac{1}{\omega}=-\frac{1}{2}\cos(q^2)+C$$

Setting $\omega=7$ at $q=0$, we get 
$$\frac{1}{7}=-\frac{1}{2}\cos(0)+C\iff C=\frac{9}{14}$$
setting the value of $C$
$$\frac{1}{\omega}=-\frac{1}{2}\cos(q^2)+\frac{9}{14}$$
Hence, the solution is $$\bbox[5pt, border:2.5pt solid #FF0000]{\color{blue}{\omega=\frac{14}{9-7\cos(q^2)}}}$$

Comment: The problem was the separation of variables, not the integration...

Comment: Thank you. I tried to work this out as a function of w alone and got w= -14/(-9+7 cos(q^2)). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes , your answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

Let $$ q^2 = p$$
omitting a few steps as an exercise for you,
$$ \frac{-2\, dw}{w^2} = \sin p \ dp $$
$$ \frac {2}{w}= -\cos p + C =-\cos q^2 + C.$$

And then evaluate $C$ in the usual plugin way to get:

$$ \frac{1}{w} = -\frac{1}{2}\cos q^2+\frac{9}{14}$$

Comment: The problem was the separation of variables, not the integration...

Answer (score 0):

Given $\displaystyle \frac{dw}{dq} = -qw^2\sin q^2\Rightarrow \frac{dw}{w^2} = -\sin q^2\cdot qdq$

Now Use Integral Sign both side, we get $\displaystyle \int\frac{dw}{w^2} = -\int \sin q^2\cdot qdq$

Now put $q^2=t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle qdq = \frac{1}{2} dt$

So we get $\displaystyle -\frac{1}{w} = \frac{1}{2}\cos q^2+\mathcal{C}$

Now Put $q=0\;,$ we get $\displaystyle -\frac{1}{7} = \frac{1}{2}+\mathcal{C}\Rightarrow \mathcal{C} = -\frac{9}{14}$

So we get $\displaystyle \frac{1}{w} = -\frac{1}{2}\cos q^2+\frac{9}{14}$

Comment: The problem was the separation of variables, not the integration...

Comment: The moment you see $ q, dq $ together, you should see that the product is differential of $ q^2/2.$